# Does VS code support virtual space?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find an option to enable virtual space in the Visual Studio Code editor. I browsed through all workspace settings, but without any luck.

Is virtual space renamed to something else or is it not supported yet?

Comment: Requests on Github ([1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/84), [2](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1515)) suggest that it is not supported.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found feedback request for this missing feature.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13960

Comment: Alas here we are in 2024 and it still hasn't been implemented... it seems none of the core contributors care about this giant hole in the editor.